# Thread 1: Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

as the title says I have that error
I would greatly appreciate help me
My code is below

this is in BTscan.c

```
t_btmanager     *bt_accessor(t_btmanager *tmp)
{
static t_btmanager  *bt_tmp = 0;
if (tmp)
bt_tmp = tmp;
return (bt_tmp);
}

int bt_scan()

{
bt_accessor(0)->status = 1;  ////Here's the problem
printf("registering hooks ...\n");
return (0);
}
```

and this one in BTscan.h

```
typedef struct  s_btmanager
{
char        status;
}       t_btmanager;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: ... Do you ever initialize your `bt_accessor` with a real `t_btmanager`? I can imagine that if you never do that, `bt_tmp` will always be null, and trying to retrieve the `status` of a null pointer will give you your error.

Answer (score 2):

`bt_tmp` will remain as `0` if `tmp` is `0`. So it becomes `NULL`  pointer and dereferencing null pointer `bt_accessor(0)->status` will cause an exception. Because memory address `0x0` is prohibited to be accessed.

I am not sure where the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception comes, but I guess it is coming from Mach kernel virtual memory manager.